# Help on OI word

Tags: word-choice

Need help in my kids’s assignment in fill in the blank with oi word related to the pic. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: No native speaker would choose *moist* there over *dripping* or *drying*.  You may wish to visit our sister site for [ell.se]. Then again, so might your kids’ teacher, alas.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had an impression that moist have water droplets but not at the level of dropping. And thanks for the link.

Comment: An odd question. The picture is a shirt (made of cloth but not called “a cloth”) and something **dripping wet** on a washing line would hardly be referred to as just “moist”. But nevertheless **moist** seems to be the only word that fits.

Comment: I say the shirt is soiled and drenched. The question is one of those "You may be right, but I have a different answer in mind. So your answer is wrong."

Comment: @YosefBaskin If it's drying on the line, it has presumably just been washed, so probably wouldn't still be soiled.